# GCTaskThread JVM Crash

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm-crash

My JVM (7.0_21-b11) is crashing randomly (sometimes after 1 day and sometime after 1 month). We are using an API that makes JNI calls. Based on quick search seems like this happens either because of faulty JNI calls or faulty RAM / DISK. 
We are running some tests and enabled -Xcheck:jni that can eliminate both of above point.

Are there any other reasons that can cause JVM to crash in these circumstances.

These are some top few lines from hs_err_pid log file.

```
**# JRE version: 7.0_21-b11
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.21-b01 mixed mode windows-amd64 )
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x31e6ec]
#
# Core dump written. Default location: c:\app\bin\hs_err_pid9099.mdmp
---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------
Current thread (0x0000000001cdc000):  GCTaskThread [stack: 0x0000000000000000,0x0000000000000000] [id=90672]
siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000000000000220**
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using very old version of Java JDK7 update 21. Crash occured in GC. GC Issue is caused by any bug that corrupts heap memory. It could be an issue with GC, with the compiler, with bad native code. Without reproducer it is hard to debug. Do you have any specif test case that can reproduce this issue, then possibly there will be solution. Suggested solution is to upgrade your java version